# Can anyone point out what is producing these false output statements

Tags: c, visual-studio

When I compile this program the output includes statements which are false. Can anyone point out what may be causing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
int num1;
int num2;

printf("enter two numbers and I will tell you the relation\n");
printf("the relation they satisfy\n");
scanf_s("%d%d" , &num1, &num2);

if (num1 == num2) {
printf("%d is equal to %d\n", num1, num2);
}

if (num1 != num2) {
printf("%d is not equal to %d\n", num1, num2);
}

if (num1 > num2); {
printf("%d is greater than %d\n", num1, num2);
}

if (num1 < num2); {
printf("%d is less than %d\n", num1, num2);
}

if (num1 >= num2); {
printf("%d is greater than or equal to %d\n", num1, num2);
}

if (num1 <= num2); {
printf("%d is less than or equal to %d\n", num1, num2);
}
}
```

After I compile this and enter, for example, 25 and 50 as my numbers. It returns the statements:

- "25 is not equal to 50"
- "25 is greater than 50"
- "25 is less than 50"
- 25 is greater than or equal to 50
- 25 is less than or equal to 50

Comment: You have a bunch of stray semicolons: `if (num1 > num2); {}` --> `if (num1 > num2) {} `.

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(   Also, did you not get a bunch of warnings upon compilation?

Answer (score 3):

```
if (num1 > num2); {
//              ^ extra semi colon
printf("%d is greater than %d\n", num1, num2);
}
```

This means: if the condition is true, do nothing
And next do the block unconditionally.

Answer (score 0):

For every if statement there is an extra Semicolon(;). That means the if condition statement has stopped execution over there and next printf statements are executing with out any condition applied